# Binomial Lattice plot in R

Tags: r, matrix, graph, lattice

I want to graph the paths of my binomial lattice by rows from the matrix, which consists the nodes of each path, for example matrix with the root node 100, the upward increment 2, the downward increment 0.5 (matrix can be any, but with the lattice node data):

```
    (1) (2) (3) (4)

(1) 100 50  100 200

(2) 100 50  25  12,5
```

So that, I want to obtain the following graph:
[image: The example with the matrix above]

And with changing the quantity of the nodes (columns in matrix) and the quantity of paths (rows in matrix) the graph must be alternated. Thanks everyone, who will help me!!!

Comment: Try  [`digraph`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html) if you have MATLAB R2015b or later.

Comment: I must use only the R staff. (Even when I plot in the Matlab using the digraph, there is the extending of distances between the terminal nodes. Thus, the terminal  nodes  stick together to the smallest terminal node, but I need the same distances between them.

Comment: Don't tag your question with MATLAB if you are not intending to use that language as part of your problem. I've taken the liberty in removing that from your tags of the question as you actually don't mention MATLAB at all.

Comment: @rayryeng, sorry, my foul